# how to fix relativeness of `em` scale in css?

Tags: html, css, mono

since `em` length scale is relative to the current font size, this problem arose.

I want the `border-width` of many elements to be one eighth of my normal font width. By normal I mean when the html document has the least necessary parts and just a text written in my font. My font is mono.

You can see how it looks:

[image: screenshot]

When I just write `border-width: 0.125em;`, borders will not have the same width.

I don't want to use `px` because I want to produce the same width on very compact displays.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `calc(1rem / 8)` to get 1/8th of `1rem` or use `0.125rem`. Using `rem` will reference the document's base font size instead of whatever `em` is throughout the document.

```css
div {
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 0.125rem solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>foo</div>
```

Comment: I think I need to provide the plain code here. Since this doesn't work. Font size isn't the same throughout the document and thus it doesn't matter if you use calc or write `0.125em`. We need to take the current font size into account.

Comment: @AHB updated my answer to reflect `rem` units, not `em`. Is that what you're going for?

Comment: @AHB yeah `rem` is super useful since `em` can get messy depending on where you are in the document

Comment: Then why do they still use `em` ? I can't see any reason.

Comment: @AHB tons of reasons. Say `h1` is `3em` and `h2` is `1.5em` and you wanted to apply a `margin-bottom` to `h1` and `h2`. It makes more sense to apply `h1,h2 { margin-bottom: .5em; }` than using individual `rem` margins so the margin will reflect half of the current font size. Lots of other reasons, too. You can find good articles by googling `em vs rem`